# Cómo redireccionar automaticamente al cargar una pagina JSF

Tags: java, jsf

Tengo una aplicacion JSF y en la pagina index.xhtml, necesito hacer 2 cosas:

1. Recoger un valor que viene en la peticion (request)
2. Redireccionar automaticamente a un bean para realizar unas operaciones con el valor recogido.

Porfa, alguien me puede colaborar?

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el parámetro:

```
Map<String, String> params =FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
               getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
String parametroDeseado = params.get("nombreParametro");
```

Para hacer la redirección:

```
ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
    .getExternalContext();
try {
   externalContext.redirect(externalContext.getRequestContextPath() + "/destino.xhtml");
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```